# Previous value in while loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, finance, montecarlo

I tried to make simple monte carlo simulation for stock investments where you start with some investment value, investment period (in years) and mean and std of stock mutual fund. I also wanted to implement an easy way for stock market crash - I did it so that whenever new calculated value was for 40 % higher than previous one, the new value should fall for 90 % - like some kind of crash. I managed to make it working and here is the code, but I think that it is not working right. The problem is probably hidden where I call previous value. Could you try to make it working?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np

mean = 7.0 #mean for stock mutual fund
std = 19.0 #std for stock mutual fund

def investment_return(): #random normal distribution of returns
    investment_return = (np.random.normal(mean,std))/100
    return investment_return

def investor(A, B):
    investment_value = A
    investment_period = B

    wX = []
    vY = []

    x = 1

    while x <= investment_period:
        value = A + A*investment_return()
        if value > value * 1.4: #if new value is 1.4x bigger than previous
            A = value * 0.1 #than make -90 percent adjustment
        else:
            A = value #else use new value
        wX.append(x)
        vY.append(value)
        x += 1
    #print(value)

    plt.plot(wX,vY)

i = 0
while i < 10: #number of investors
    investor(100,20) #starting value and investment period
    i += 1

plt.ylabel('Investment_value')
plt.xlabel('Investment_period')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is not working, can you explain specifically what you input, what was output and what you expected as output?

Comment: `if value > value * 1.4:` is definitely not going to work. Python has no way of guessing which of those `value`s means "the new value" and which means "the previous value". Hint: maybe you need to explicitly make a `previous_value` variable...

Comment: Don't you want `vY.append(A)`?

Comment: @Kevin ...yup..I think that there should be a problem..it's just that I don't know how to add it into the code. Tried a lot of things. And the problem is because `previous_value` should change at every iteration. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I tried best I could to interpret what you were after. It helped that you provided a solid basis to work with :).

Ok so, here we go: obviously, Kevin's remark that `value > value * 1.4` will never evaluate to `True` is a solid one. I did rename some variables (for example, normally we compare stocks as `indices`, so I renamed `A` to `index`). Time is generally referred to as `t`, not `x`. The `while` loops were a little quirky, so I got rid of those.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


mean = 7.0
std = 19.0


def investment_return():
    return (np.random.normal(mean, std)) / 100


def investor(index, period):
    wT = []
    vY = []

    for t in range(1, period + 1):
        new_index = index + index * investment_return()
        if new_index > index * 1.4:
            index = new_index * 0.1
        else:
            index = new_index
        wT.append(t)
        vY.append(index)
    return wT, vY


for i in range(0, 10):
    wT, vY = investor(100, 20)

    # do something with your data

    plt.plot(wT, vY)

plt.ylabel('Investment_value')
plt.xlabel('Investment_period')
plt.show()
```

This occasionally does have a stock crash, as can clearly be seen (do keep in mind that this requires you to sample `>40` from an `N(7,19)` distribution: that should not happen in a little over `95%` of all cases).

Comment: I think this is a great answer, but I think you need `range(1, period+1)` to match the `>=` in the original code's `while` loop. I might also use `value` and `new_value` as variable names, rather than differentiating between `index` and `value` which are really just the same thing in different periods.

Comment: @Blckknght quite correct, I'll update my answer. With regard to `value` vs `index`: not sure, but that would work too (having everything start at `100` as in OP's code seemed very `indexy` to me).

Comment: My point is mostly that the two variables in your code really represent the same thing at different times and should have related names. Whether that's `value` and `new_value` or `index` and `new_index` is a separate issue that I have no opinion on.

Comment: Wow, that's a great answer :) and it really works.. thanks @N.Wouda, I really appreciate your help. While checking your answer I came across a new question - what if I want to compare my value to some other previous value (not only the last one, but let's say to three or five periods before this one)?

Comment: @Blckknght makes perfect sense when put like that. I updated my answer accordingly, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @DavidV I updated my code so that `investor()` now returns the data, rather than just plot it. That should allow you to do with it whatever you like :).

Comment: @N.Wouda..and just to add another comment: two-sigma events should be really rare in real life (5 % or less of the time), but they are not so rare in financial world. With this simulation I would just like to prove to my co-workers that sometimes shit just happens :) and we do not have any chance to tell when it's going to happen.

Comment: @DavidV I just looked it up in a normal table, and sampling `>40` from an `N(7, 19)` distribution happens in about 4% of all cases.

Comment: @N.Wouda.. true :) but finances are not normal distribution event..eheheh..btw, I have another question: what if I want to compare my value to some other previous value (not only the last one, but let's say to three or five periods before this one)? how could that be done? thanks in advance..

Comment: @DavidV you have all data per investor available to you where I placed the comment in my code. Alternatively, if you have a specific requirement, I'd suggest opening a new question and maybe linking me in a comment to it (so that I can see it too :)).